# Configure the Actuator after migrate Spring Boot 1.5.6 to Spring Boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I decided to update Spring Boot from version 1.5.6 to version 2.0.0. There was a multitude of errors, one of them being the actuator. My previous configuration in version 1.5.6 looked like this

```
management:
  context-path: /actuator
  security:
    roles: ADMIN

endpoints:
  enabled: true
  sensitive: true
```

I had all addresses working, and only a logged in user (Spring Security) with the role ADMIN had access to them. After updating Spring Boot to version 2.0.0, my partial configuration looks like this

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
      base-path: /actuator
```

But I do not know how to set up access to Actuator addresses only if the user logged in with the ADMIN role.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your Spring Security configuration like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ...
        // secure only specific actuator endpoint
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("env"))
            .hasRole("ADMIN");

       // or secure all actuator endpoints
       http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .hasRole("ADMIN");
 }
}
```